# login error message when user is inactive

Tags: laravel

I have Laravel code that of login auth page, the problem is that when I login the inactive user, I should get error message that your user is not activated.

My code

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only(['username', 'password']);

    $validator = Validator::make($credentials, [
        'username' => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    // If the user is activated then value will be 1 and not activated user will 0
    // <--- THIS LINE

    if(!$credentials['active'] = 1)
    {
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors(['username' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage()]);
    }

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
    }

    if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($credentials)) {
        admin_toastr(trans('admin::lang.login_successful'));

        return redirect()->intended(config('admin.prefix'));
    }


    return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors(['username' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage()]);
}
```

Comment: if(!$credentials['active'] = 1)
    {
      //can i put error message here.
    }

Answer (score 0):

You haven't used the correct operator in your if statement. change

```
if(!$credentials['active'] = 1)
{
    return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
    return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors(['username' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage()]);
}
```

to

```
if(!$credentials['active'] == 1)
{
   return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
   return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors(['username' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage()]);
}
```

OR

```
if($credentials['active'] != 1)
{
   return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
   return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors(['username' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage()]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but i have copy your code and tested but it won work, actually my problem is that when i put my code,
if(!$credentials['active'] = 1) { return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator); return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors(['username' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage()]); }

it work but i am receiving the same error messages like username and password incorrect. so, i want that when user is inactive i should get message saying "your user is not activated". ..please help me..